# How do I obtain a raw json string from an environment variable in python?

Tags: python, json, environ

In BASH, I can store JSON into an environment variable via jq:

```
export FOO=$(curl ... | jq -Rs)
```

Now, if I load that into python:

```
bar=os.environ["FOO"]
```

`bar` will have something like: `{\\"this\\":\\"that\\"}`, which is a problem when loading with `json`:

```
json.loads(bar) # error
```

---

I have tried a few things including `repr`, `rf'{os.environ["FOO"]}'` and so on, but there doesn't seem to be an internally managed way to drop the extra slashes.

How do I drop the extra slashes via string functions? I'd prefer not to simply replace them with a single slash, as I might have to touch that code again sometime in the future.

Comment: I suggest you look at the value of the environment variable in sh or other, I could not reproduce the issue with json in an environment variable, I think it's not a python issue.

Comment: @Hyalunar it was the IDE. I was referencing the env file via Pycharm's configurable debug entrypoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `-r` flag to output as raw text from `jq`.  Here is an example using echo that gives the escaped results:

```
echo '{"fruit":{"name":"apple","color":"green","price":1.20}}' | jq -Rs
# gives:
"{\"fruit\":{\"name\":\"apple\",\"color\":\"green\",\"price\":1.20}}\n"
```

But adding `-r` gives a result that is still in JSON format without all of the escaped quotes:

```
echo '{"fruit":{"name":"apple","color":"green","price":1.20}}' | jq -Rsr
# gives:
{"fruit":{"name":"apple","color":"green","price":1.20}}
```

Which is parseable by Python.

```
export FOO=$(echo '{"fruit":{"name":"apple","color":"green","price":1.20}}' | jq -Rsr)
```

```py
import os
import json

json.loads(os.environ['FOO'])
# returns:
# {'fruit': {'name': 'apple', 'color': 'green', 'price': 1.2}}
```

Comment: this got around the issue, which was an IDE bug.

Comment: I preferred to have it within double quotes, since I am substituting the raw json into a project `.env` file via `envsubst`, but it looks like raw json gets set to the variable just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reconstruct this:

```
export FOO=$(curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1|jq -Rs)
```

This is what is stored from the looks in bash:

```
"{\n \"userId\": 1,\n \"id\": 1,\n \"title\": \"delectus aut autem\",\n \"completed\": false\n}"
```

Then in python shell:

```
>>> import json
>>> import os
>>> json.loads(json.loads(os.environ["FOO"]))
{'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'delectus aut autem', 'completed': False}
```

So basically json.loads() doesn't give you any guarantees regarding the type of Python object you get, but it tries to de-serialize whatever you feed it and so a nested de-serialization does the job. But of course, it is better, if you can make sure that the environment contains the data in the correct format in the first place as the other answer suggests.

Comment: yeah, it was a Pycharm issue.